# Cobalt debug build for raspi failing to load video

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, cobalt

I'm trying to run cobalt on raspi it loads youtube homepage by default. From that page I'm trying to select and play a video and then it crashes giving this error:

```
[0612/083342:INFO:fetcher_factory.cc(94)] Fetching: https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai=AKA[...]
[0612/083344:INFO:fetcher_factory.cc(94)] Fetching: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?rt[...]
[0612/083347:INFO:fetcher_factory.cc(94)] Fetching: https://i9.ytimg.com/sb/lEmfbJvjRmQ/storyboard3_L2/M0.j[...]
[0612/083350:INFO:fetcher_factory.cc(94)] Fetching: https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=[...]
[0612/083351:INFO:web_media_player_impl.cc(753)] Trying to stop media pipeline.
[0612/083351:INFO:web_media_player_impl.cc(757)] Media pipeline stopped.
[0612/083351:WARNING:html_media_element.cc(842)] HTMLMediaElement::LoadInternal, nothing to load
[0612/083351:INFO:web_media_player_impl.cc(753)] Trying to stop media pipeline.
[0612/083351:INFO:web_media_player_impl.cc(757)] Media pipeline stopped.
[0612/083352:INFO:fetcher_factory.cc(94)] Fetching: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?rt[...]
[0612/083353:WARNING:resource_cache.h(286)] Error while loading 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?rt=xfp&lid=17&sdkv=h.3.0.0&id=ima_html5&c=4427383555541194&domain=www.youtube.com': No content returned. Not an image mime type.
[0612/083353:INFO:html_media_element.cc(883)] HTMLMediaElement::LoadResource(blob:EC8637FE-C7F6-EF1D-6EB5-B6E6161FEB61, , 
[0612/083353:INFO:html_media_element.cc(875)] HTMLMediaElement::LoadInternal, using 'src' attribute url
[0612/083353:INFO:chunk_demuxer.cc(427)] This is an ASYNC MEDIA SOURCE playback.
[0612/083354:WARNING:resource_cache.h(286)] Error while loading 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?rt=adsense&lid=17&sdkv=h.3.0.0&id=ima_html5&c=4427383555541194&domain=www.youtube.com': No content returned. Not an image mime type.
[0612/083354:WARNING:resource_cache.h(286)] Error while loading 'https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai=AKAOjsuLfzWOdCh6XlNNBh4oVNi8m7zw-fW4zxpMcUu8D5H0162Zm11nBaLftKIh9f4lWY-TPEw7gSN2UO1YlyoYf223TNdeGdVF40wVEVi6SLz6o0B3lYD7S3Et8dsBQtEy_fahC77s-cUd9dpdT91vVsXp1LOXIYxPtE6ia_We3PZsDFWLTv_YxgM-BYEgeUONkR_pTzgE0au5MMBTGxhQp__16yByrsuNeT-dZOqHAaqGps6cT7PXRnp3Seh6u__R&sig=Cg0ArKJSzH8Pyur8bu_gEAE&adurl=': No content returned, but expected some. Not an image mime type.
[0612/083355:INFO:media_source.cc(194)] add SourceBuffer with type audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"
[0612/083355:INFO:media_source.cc(331)] MediaSource::IsTypeSupported(audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2") -> probably/true
[0612/083355:INFO:media_source.cc(194)] add SourceBuffer with type video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400c"
[0612/083355:INFO:media_source.cc(331)] MediaSource::IsTypeSupported(video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400c") -> probably/true
[0612/083356:WARNING:resource_cache.h(286)] Error while loading 'https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/ads?ver=2&ns=1&event=5&device=7&content_v=lEmfbJvjRmQ&el=leanback&ei=VYUfW9_1PM-w1Aa51Y24CQ&devicever=6.20180220&cplayer=2&format=0_2_0&break_type=1&conn=0&cpn=0yWDksSgCfQVwLiu&lact=26722&m_pos=0&mt=[MT]&p_h=[P_H]&p_w=[P_W]&rwt=[RWT]&sdkv=h.3.0.0&slot_pos=0&vis=0&vol=[VOL]&wt=1528792430928&ad_id=&ad_len=[AD_LEN]&ad_mt=[AD_MT]&ad_sys=YT%3AAdSense&ad_v=0&blocking_error=0&error_msg=Ad%20request%20reached%20a%20timeout.&ima_error=301&internal_id=0&error_code=3&aqi=': No content returned. Not an image mime type.
[0612/083356:WARNING:resource_cache.h(286)] Error while loading 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?rt=adsense&ec=8&lid=18&sdkv=h.3.0.0&id=ima_html5&c=4427383555541194&domain=www.youtube.com': No content returned. Not an image mime type.
[1722:9824445116:ERROR:player_internal.cc(134)] Not implemented reached in void SbPlayerPrivate::SetVolume(double)
[1724:9824481396:WARNING:thread_set_name.cc(36)] Thread name "omx_video_decoder" was truncated to "omx_video_decod"
[1723:9824482412:INFO:player_worker.cc(136)] Try to seek to timestamp 0
[1724:9824485226:INFO:open_max_component_base.cc(82)] Opened "OMX.broadcom.video_decode" with port 130 and 131
[1726:9824535504:FATAL:open_max_component.cc(216)] Check failed: false. OMX_EventError received with 80001000 0
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponent::OnErrorEvent() [0x17eedd8]
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponentBase::OnEvent() [0x17f34ec]
    starboard::raspi::shared::open_max::OpenMaxComponentBase::EventHandler() [0x17f375c]
```

I have tried to run cobalt master, release_11 and release 9 too but it gives the same error on release 9 and 11 also crashing at a similar stage in master. I understand that master branch uses ffmpeg but the other two uses open Max. I tried linux build of release 9 and found it working. Can somebody tell me what is going wrong with raspi build of cobalt.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps at here? https://www.cobalt.dev/development/setup-raspi.html Was there any issues when following up the instructions?

Comment: @Daniel Juyung Seo yes i did. As a matter of fact i tried with raspi_gold then it was not crashing like this. This error is generated in debug build. But in rapsi_gold also cobalt is unable to play the video

Comment: I tried both HD and lower quality videos and in both cases only the buffering gif was displayed but not the video. Are any additional libraries required other than those mentioned in the link that you gave in your comment.